# Single gravitational plane wave or their interference can carry spin angular momentum?

Tags: gravity, conservation-laws, gravitational-waves, plane-wave

I would be grateful if anybody could tell me if I had one gravitational wave in the form of a plane wave, it still would carry spin angular momentum? We know that gravitational waves are mostly the interference between many gravitational waves from different sources like binary black holes. I think they carry spin and angular momentum due to conservation laws but I do not know, Do we have a single GW and it can carry Spin and angular momentum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that any angular momentum carried by a (transverse) wave would be associated with a circular (or elliptical) polarization.

Comment: And the reason for this should be that the quanta of gravity - if existing - do not consist of two different quanta and do not have a dipole moment. The disturbance of the gravitational field by a rotating source has a circular component in some directions and the circular component in others

Comment: @HolgerFiedler, Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain more?

Comment: @R.W.Bird Please give me more details if possible.

Comment: A transverse wave with circular polarization, when acting on an object tends to move it in a circle.